# javascript event handler not working (button click - google says null)

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I've looked over a number of threads here of similar problems to little avail - I can't figure out exactly what's going wrong here. Google claims that the element I'm trying to reference is null

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at sales.js:12
```

and no matter how I've tried to fix it, it doesn't seem to work. As you can see in the js code, I've tried a number of ways of fixing it based on stuff I've found here.

Originally the `<script src ="sales.js">` in the HTML file was up in the head, but I read in some pages here that putting it there can make it load before everything else and to put it down before the HTML closing tag.

Any suggestions?

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sales Tax Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <h1>Sales Calculator</h1>
    <p>Complete the form and click "Calculate".</p>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Item Information
        </legend>
        <label for="item">Item:</label>
        <input type="text" id="item" ><br>

        <label for="price">Price:</label>
        <input type="text" id="price" ><br>

        <label for="discount">Discount %:</label>
        <input type="text" id="discount" ><br>

        <label for="taxRate">Tax Rate:</label>
        <input type="text" id="taxRate" ><br>

        <label for="total">Discount Price:</label>
        <input type="text" id="discountPrice" disabled ><br>

        <label for="salesTax">Sales Tax:</label>
        <input type="text" id="salesTax" disabled ><br>

        <label for="total">Total:</label>
        <input type="text" id="total" disabled ><br><br>

        <div id="buttons">
        <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate" >
        <input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear" ><br></div>
    </fieldset>
    <pre>&copy; Fall 2020 Rob Honomichl - Dakota State University</pre>
</main>
</body>
<script src="sales.js"></script>
</html>
```

JS Code:

```
//"use strict"

var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id); 
};

//window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    //$("#calculate").addEventListener("click", processEntries);
//});

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById("#calculate").addEventListener("click", processEntries);
});

//window.onload = function(){
    //$("#calculate").addEventListener("click", processEntries);
//};

const processEntries = () => {
    //Gather User Input
    //var item = document.querySelector("#item").value;
    var price = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#price").value).toFixed(2);
    var discount = parseInt(document.querySelector("#discount").value);
    var taxRate = parseInt(document.querySelector("#taxRate").value);

    //Calculate Discounted Price
    function discountPriceCalc(price, discount) {
        const disPrice = price * (discount/100);
        return disPrice.toFixed(2);
    }

    //Calculate Sales Tax
    function salesTaxCalc(discountPrice, taxRate) {
        const taxTotal = price * (taxRate/100);
        return taxTotal.toFixed(2);
    }

    //Calculate Total
    function totalCalc(discountPrice, salesTax) {
         return ((Number(discountPrice) + Number(salesTax).toFixed(2)));
    }

    //Calculate the disabled text box values
    var discountPrice = discountPriceCalc(price, discount);
    var salesTax = salesTaxCalc(discountPrice, taxRate);
    var Total = totalCalc(discountPrice, salesTax);

    //Update Text Boxes
    document.getElementById("discountPrice").value = discountPrice;
    document.getElementById("salesTax").value = salesTax;
    document.getElementById("total").value = Total;

    //set focus to Item box after
    document.getElementById("item").focus();
};
```

Comment: remove the `#` in `document.getElementById("#calculate")` - why are you mixing getElementById and querySelector for accessing elements by id? use one or the other consistently - then such typos won't happen

Comment: `document.querySelector` uses `.` and `#` at the beginning, but if you are using `document.getElementsByClassName` or `document.getElementById` you just provide name of the calss or id respectively.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get rid of the # in the getElementById call to properly locate the element.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", processEntries);
});
```